# Different notations for the length of the line segment

Tags: geometry, notation

This one is very trivial, I was just wondering, can the notation for the length of the line segment be written like this:

$$|\overline{AB}|=5~\text{cm}$$

I noticed that in different parts of the world, people use different notations. For example, in United States, the most common notation is simply $AB=5~\text{cm}$, and in Croatia, the notation is $|AB|=5~\text{cm}$ and never different. I even came across the notation which places the letter "m" before the line segment to indicate the length (although this notation is very suspicious to me). Since the notations are so versatile, is it mathematically correct to state this $|\overline{AB}|=5~\text{cm}$ as well?

Comment: The overline seems overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The units of length, such as "cm", "m", are used in physics; they are not used in pure mathematical discussions.

Notations are mostly for communications. As long as the context is clear, you can use whatever notations you like. Though you may want to follow certain conventions.